# Prove that sequence defined by composition of a function is bounded given that function's derivative is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that its derivative $f'(x)$.
> is a continuous function. Moreover, assume that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $$0 \leq |f'(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$ Define a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $$a_1=1$$ $$a_{n+1} = f(a_n) $$for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that there exists a positive real number $M$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $$|a_n| \leq M.$$
> [Source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGB-2018.pdf)

---

My attempt:

We use the Mean Value Theorem. $$\frac{f(a_n)-f(a_{n-1})}{a_n-a_{n-1}} = f'(x)$$ for some $x \in [a_n,a_{n-1}]$. We know that $-\frac{1}{2} \leq f'(x)\leq \frac{1}{2}$, hence $$-\frac{1}{2} \leq\frac{f(a_n)-f(a_{n-1})}{a_n-a_{n-1}} \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$ Simplifying, we find that $|a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq \frac{|a_n-a_{n-1}|}{2}$.

Here we define a sequence $x_n = |a_{n+1} -a_n|.$ It is easy to see that $x_n \leq \frac{x_{n-1}}{2}$ which implies that $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = 0$$ Which means that $|a_{n-1} - a_n|$ is arbitrarily small and grows slower than $\{X_n : X_n = \Sigma \frac{1}{2^n} \}$. Therefore the sequence must converge to a finite limit, say $L$. We choose $M = L+1$.

QED.

---

Is this proof correct? I have a few qualms about it, but a few of my peers looked over it and weren't able to find any problem with it. Please help me with a nudge in the right direction if there turns out to be an error.

Comment: The fact that $|a_{n+1}-a_n|$ tends to $0$ does not imply that $(a_n)$ converges. Moreover, if $(a_n)$ tends to $L$, then it is not necessarily bounded by $L+1$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Ah, yes, thank you. I forgot to prove whether the function was monotonic or not.

Comment: Even if $(a_n)$ is monotonic, the implication is not true. For example, if $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n 1/k$, then $(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ tends to $0$, but $(a_n)$ does not converge...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I understand that, however the fact that the function grows slower than $X_n = \Sigma_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2^i}$ *would* imply that it converges (unless I am mistaken).

Comment: "The fact that the function grows slower than..." - Can you turn that into an argument that $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: This isn't really a proof, but intuitively it's easy to see that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with $K=\frac{1}{2}$, and therefore $a_{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{2} a_n$, so the sequence ($a_n$) converges to $0$. Unless I'm misunderstanding something? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity

Comment: @Lt.Commander.Data You are right, but for me, this step needs a little more details. Indeed, as Stinkingbishop says, the more natural way is to prove that $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @AdamRubinson $f$ is $1/2$-Lipschitz does not mean that $f(x) \leq x/2$ ...

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thank you, I will do that.

Comment: Does the sequence necessarily converge to a fixed point? Even if not, I feel like we can use Banach fixed-point theorem somehow.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes, this statement is sort of contained in the Banach fixed-point theorem. But I guess the exercise is to prove it without the theorem ;)

Comment: I see. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've essentially proved that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_{k+1} - a_k|$ converges. This means $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{k+1} - a_k)$ also converges, and if you define
$$L = a_1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (a_{k+1} - a_k)$$
you get
$$L - a_n = \sum_{k=n}^\infty (a_{k+1} - a_k)$$ for all $n$, and in particular
$$|L - a_n| \le \sum_{k=n}^\infty |a_{k+1} - a_k| \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Ooh, thank you very much. This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Hints : use the fact, for $m\gt n $, $|a_{m}-a_{n}|\le |a_{m}-a_{m-1}|+|a_{m-1}-a_{m-2}|+\cdot\cdot\cdot+|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|\le \frac{1}{2^{m-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{m-2}}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac{1}{2^{n}} $

Right hand side series is a G.P. series with ratio $\frac{1}{2}$.